# Places near Durch Caves

Tags: europe, spain, southeast-europe, caves, mallorca

We are planning to do a day trip to the Coves del Drac area. We will take public transport from Palma.

Are there any other worthy nearby places that we could visit on the same day using public transport? Could be nice beaches or any other touristy sites.

Answer (score 3):

Cuevas del Drach is an awesome place to enjoy the music and experience the lake that exists under the caves. It took a half-day to visit this place.

The nearest places to grab the adventurous experience are Viu Aventura and Caminito Beach for quick reach. Dinosaurland and Safari Zoo would be great to visit with the kids.